# setting breaks in ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make several histograms regarding the same vector of values and a density estimation. So the next plot is good.

```
 values = rnorm(100)
 plot = ggplot(data.frame(val=values), aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + geom_density()
```

However, I need to print several plots (not one plot with different panels) with different break points, say:

```
breaks = list(c(-1,0,1),c(-2,-1.5,0,1.5,2),c(-0.5,0,0.5))
```

How can I redefine the breaks for the variable `plot`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your own code, you can do that with:

```
ggplot(data.frame(val=values), aes(x=val)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_density() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-2,-1.5,0,1.5,2))
```

Comment: Also works if you just put the `breaks` inside the `geom_histogram`, though the axis is definitely clearer your way.

Comment: thanks, I was confused and trying with the breaks argument in `geom_histogram`. I have just started with ggplot2 and I feel like an idiot even trying to do the simplest things. I guess I would get the trick with time.

Comment: @Usobi A good reference for ggplot2 is [the online documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html). A good book about ggplot2 is *"R Graphics Cookbook"* by *Winston Chang*.

Comment: aw! I knew about the online documentation but the book you suggested was unknown to me and seems even better.