# set binwidth to value for ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble creating a histogram using ggplot.

I have a data structure as follows:

```
value_1
112.45
2457.44
333.24
```

And this list of values continues for about 25000 more observations.

I want a histogram that has bins of the frequency of values 0-100 then 100-200 then 200-300 all up to the upper limit of values.

In the example above that would give 1 count in the bin 100-200, 1 count in the bin 300-400 and one count in the bin 2400-2500.

Could you help me in the right direction?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031060/setting-breaks-in-ggplot2-histogram

Comment: @mt1022 then maybe this is right duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231109/stacked-histogram-from-already-summarized-counts-using-ggplot2

Comment: @zx8754. I am afraid not. for this question, what the OP wants seems to be  setting either `center` or `boundary` with `binwidth` at the same time in `geom_histogram`.

Comment: @mt1022 feel free to answer, my bad, just trying to find a good dupe. From the title it sounded the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the right bin width by setting the `binwidth` and either `center` or `boundary` at the same time:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(112.45, 2457.44, 333.24))

library(ggplot2)  # 2.2.1
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 100, center = 150)
# or
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 100, boundary = 100)
```

> center
>
> The center of one of the bins. Note that if center is above or
>   below the range of the data, things will be shifted by an appropriate
>   number of widths. To center on integers, for example, use width = 1
>   and center = 0, even if 0 is outside the range of the data. At most
>   one of center and boundary may be specified.
>
> boundary
>
> A boundary
>   between two bins. As with center, things are shifted when boundary is
>   outside the range of the data. For example, to center on integers, use
>   width = 1 and boundary = 0.5, even if 0.5 is outside the range of the
>   data. At most one of center and boundary may be specified.

If you known the range of the data, you can also set this manually with `breaks =` in `geom_histogram` only.